# Do the JavaScript bindings for Selenium have a staleness indicator?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm using JavaScript bindings for Selenium to automate a web application and I came across this exception

> StaleElementReferenceError: Element not found in the cache - perhaps
>   the page has changed since it was looked up
>
> For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

In Java I have used the `webDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));`, is there any such method in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: this.quickSearchOfText = function(){
        commUtil.getTextUsingWebElement(enterTheText).then(function(TextValue){
            console.log(textValue);

        });


    };

Comment: The "enterTheText" is a webelement, that element throws "StaleElementReferenceError"

Comment: Java's ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf() you mentioned will block execution until an element is stale. But you need your element to NOT be stale in order to avoid this error, so that method will not help you. Does anything happen on the page between the time when you select the element and when you pass it to this function here? That could cause the element to be stale. Try selecting the element immediately before passing in to this function.

Comment: Also you'll need to reconcile the different casing between TextValue and textValue.

Comment: I have used the stalenessOf() method in java, my requirement now is to know any method that can help with the StaleElementReferenceError in javascript as I'm using webdriverjs now.